# How to create favorite in DataGrid?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have got a DataGrid, and I want create there a favorite icon (like "star off" and "star on"). When favorite (the star) is clicked, it should send 1 to the server if the star is going on, or send 0 to the server if the star is going off.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to do this server-side or client-side (Javascript)? Give more context, please.

Comment: I've elements with ID in DataGrid. If user clicks on star(favorite), I must send to server 1 or 0. It would be great if on client-side..

Comment: Your question is too broad to reasonably answer.  Are you looking for 1. the server code to update the DB, 2. the client code to send your favorite request, or 3. the interface code to change the star icon / track the star's current state?

Comment: Just 2 variant, The client side which sends requests on click.